# Identify Cells in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to hide the label in a tapped cell and instead show an Image. Also I want to store this state and show the image only if a certain other cell is already displaying an image. I have a set number of cells.
I did it with the indexPath but the cells are reused at scrolling.
How can I address the cells and store data?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("user tapped on cell number \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    if (cell.myLabel.text == "1") {
        one = true

            if (cell.myLabel.hidden) {
                cell.myLabel.hidden = false
                cell.MyImageView.image = nil

            }
            else {
                cell.myLabel.hidden = true
                cell.MyImageView.image = UIImage(named:"1")!
            }
    }
```

Comment: i think you want something like matching game. is it so? You're facing issues because you are not describing the exact problem.  @Maidi

Comment: I think you are examining the problem from a wrong direction; your data source serves the view, not the opposite; therefore your data source __has to__ store such information about your item, and obviously you need to update your data source only. then when you present a cell in your delegate class you will extract the information from your data source again and create the view according to that info, which has been stored there __already__.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the state in the cell, you should save it in some dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your cell for row at index path method, i'm going to assume you don't have an array of objects you can mutate... otherwise instead of having a mutable dictionary you can add a variable to those objects and set it to `true`

You'll need a mutable dictionary

`var selectedIndexes:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()`

then when your cell is selected

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

println("user tapped on cell number \(indexPath.row)")

   let keystring = String(format:"%i", indexPath.row)

   if self.selectedIndexes[keystring] {

       println("cell has been selected before")

       // maybe you want to revert the behaviour? 
   }
   else {

       self.selectedIndexes.setObject(keystring, forKey: keystring)

       let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

       // The criteria wasn't clear when to do you hide code... so whatever you'd like the behaviour to be, check / do it here.

   }
}
```

then in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let keystring = String(format:"%i", indexPath.row)

   if self.selectedIndexes[keystring] {

   // layout your cell in it's selected state 

   }
   else { 

   // your normal unselected cell 

   }

}
```

As I said in the comments it wasn't clear exactly when you wanted certain behaviour... but a simple principle is to add items to a dictionary based on a key related to the index path row.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the cells are still reused at scrolling so the image appears at cells that haven't been selected

Comment: That's what `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is for... The dictionary should be in your view controller not in your cell.